# Как работать с jsoncpp?

Tags: c++, json, парсер, mingw

Хочу воспользоваться библиотекой jsoncpp. 
Скачал с [github](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), поставил с помощью cmake, как указано в [документации](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/README.md). 
Только вот не могу ничего скомпилировать. 
Пример из документации вылетает с ошибками компиляции:

```
#include <json/value.h>

Json::Value root;   // starts as "null"; will contain the root value after parsing
std::cin >> root;

// Get the value of the member of root named 'my-encoding', return 'UTF-32' if there is no
// such member.
std::string my_encoding = root.get("my-encoding", "UTF-32" ).asString();

// Get the value of the member of root named 'my-plug-ins'; return a 'null' value if
// there is no such member.
const Json::Value my_plugins = root["my-plug-ins"];
for ( int index = 0; index < my_plugins.size(); ++index )  // Iterates over the sequence elements.
   yourib::loadPlugIn( my_plugins[index].asString() );

yourlib::setIndentLength( root["my-indent"].get("length", 3).asInt() );
yourlib::setIndentUseSpace( root["my-indent"].get("use_space", true).asBool() );

// ...
// At application shutdown to make the new configuration document:
// Since Json::Value has implicit constructor for all value types, it is not
// necessary to explicitly construct the Json::Value object:
root["encoding"] = yourlib::getCurrentEncoding();
root["indent"]["length"] = yourlib::getCurrentIndentLength();
root["indent"]["use_space"] = yourlib::getCurrentIndentUseSpace();

// Make a new JSON document with the new configuration. Preserve original comments.
std::cout << root << "\n";
```

Ошибки:

```
a.cpp:18:4: error: ‘yourib’ has not been declared
    yourib::loadPlugIn( my_plugins[index].asString() );
    ^
a.cpp:20:1: error: ‘yourlib’ has not been declared
 yourlib::setIndentLength( root["my-indent"].get("length", 3).asInt() );
 ^
a.cpp:21:1: error: ‘yourlib’ has not been declared
 yourlib::setIndentUseSpace( root["my-indent"].get("use_space", true).asBool() );
 ^
a.cpp:27:20: error: ‘yourlib’ has not been declared
 root["encoding"] = yourlib::getCurrentEncoding();
                    ^
a.cpp:28:28: error: ‘yourlib’ has not been declared
 root["indent"]["length"] = yourlib::getCurrentIndentLength();
                            ^
a.cpp:29:31: error: ‘yourlib’ has not been declared
 root["indent"]["use_space"] = yourlib::getCurrentIndentUseSpace();
                               ^
```

Компилятор: MinGW

В сети не нашёл детального объяснения использования данной библиотеки. 
Прошу, поделитесь опытом: как скомпилировать данный пример?

#### UPDATE

Если всё запихнуть в метод и сделать некоторые замены, то количество ошибок вообще зашкаливает:

```
#include <json/value.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    Json::Value root;  
    std::cin >> root;
    std::string my_encoding = root.get("my-encoding", "UTF-32" ).asString();

    const Json::Value my_plugins = root["my-plug-ins"];
    root["encoding"] = "cp1251";
    //std::cout << root << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Часть ошибок:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:222:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Json::Value’ to ‘long double&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:235:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
       operator>>(void*& __p)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:235:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Json::Value’ to ‘void*&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:259:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
       operator>>(__streambuf_type* __sb);
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:259:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Json::Value’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:779:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:779:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   cannot convert ‘root’ (type ‘Json::Value’) to type ‘signed char*’
  std::cin >> root;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:774:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:774:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   cannot convert ‘root’ (type ‘Json::Value’) to type ‘unsigned char*’
  std::cin >> root;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:732:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, signed char& __c)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:732:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   cannot convert ‘root’ (type ‘Json::Value’) to type ‘signed char&’
  std::cin >> root;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:727:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __in, unsigned char& __c)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:727:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   cannot convert ‘root’ (type ‘Json::Value’) to type ‘unsigned char&’
  std::cin >> root;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:882:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:923:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT& __c)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:923:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘Json::Value’)
  std::cin >> root;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:882:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:955:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in, _CharT* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:955:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   mismatched types ‘_CharT2*’ and ‘Json::Value’
  std::cin >> root;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/json/value.h:12,
                 from a.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __in,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.tcc:996:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
a.cpp:6:14: note:   ‘Json::Value’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
  std::cin >> root;
```

Comment: Не нашёл приведённый код по ссылке на документацию. Где именно вы его взяли? Название yourlib (yourib — это, вероятно, опечатка) переводится как «ваша библиотека», что уже наводит на подозрения, что этот пример надо как-то модифицировать под свою задачу.

Comment: @velikodniy : https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/wiki

Comment: Ну, конкретно в таком виде пример и не должен компилироваться.

Comment: Подписался на комментарии.

Comment: @VladD, я сделал так, как вы сказали. И ещё засунул всё это дело в функцию, добавив `iostream` в заголовок. Теперь очень много ошибок. Обновляю вопрос.

Comment: @LEQADA: Давайте!

Comment: @VladD, обновил

Comment: @LEQADA: О, это уже интереснее. А на какую строку ругается? На `cin << root;`?

Comment: Если так, то вы недоподключили какой-то header.

Comment: @VladD, в самом начале это, да.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32879/discussion-between-leqada-and-vladd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наконец-то удалось заставить работать эту библиотеку. Я пользовался GCC версии 4.8.4 и Python 2.7.6. Нужно скачать библиотеку с официального GitHub репозитория и разархивировать куда-нибудь. Затем в в терминале перейти в получившуюся директорию и запустить:

```
python amalgamate.py
```

После того, как увидите сообщение `Source succesfully amalagated` в этой папке появится новая директория `dist`. Там есть файлы библиотеки, которые нам понадобятся. Содержимое папки `dist` можно свободно перемещать куда-угодно. Структура у неё следующая :

```
dist
|-- json
|   |-- json-forwards.h
|   `-- json.h
`-- jsoncpp.cpp
```

В качестве примера можно использовать этот код:

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

Json::Value root;   // starts as "null"; will contain the root value after parsing

root["encoding"] = "UTF-8";
root["indent"]["length"] = "Some text";
root["indent"]["use_space"] = "Some user_space text";

std::cout << root << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Сохраняем этот код в файл с названием **a.cpp** (можно любое другое) и кладём его рядом с файлом **jsoncpp.cpp**. А теперь из командной строки выполняем:

```
g++ a.cpp jsoncpp.cpp -std=c++11
```

При успешной компиляции никакого вывода в консоль тут быть не должно. После этого выполняем:

```
./a.out
```

и видим результат:

```
{
    "encoding" : "UTF-8",
    "indent" : 
    {
        "length" : "Some text",
        "use_space" : "Some user_space text"
    }
}
```

Спасибо большое [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) за помощь в этом запутанном деле.

Comment: #include <json/json.h> лутше указывать как #include "json/json.h" А то он будет ломится в системную директорию с библиотеками, и скажет что json не найден... ну это ИМХО у меня только так заработало

Answer (score 7):

Вообще-то тут под `yourlib` подразумевается объект вашего класса, который имеет методы `loadPlugIn()`, `setIndentLength()` и т.д. Это не значит, что вам обязательно создавать такой объект и жёстко следовать интерфейсам, которые указаны в примере. Потому что это - всего лишь **пример**, в нём показано как **теоретически** можно использовать JSONCPP.

Answer (score 0):

Немного пофлудю:
Установка: sudo aptitude install libjsoncpp-dev
Подключаем либу(в данном случае в фале *.pro): LIBS += -ljsoncpp

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
using namespace Json;
...
Value root
//манипуляции(согласно документации)...
return root.asString(); //видим результат.
```